# Gcc search path for crt1.o and crti.o

Tags: gcc, linker

I have compiled a cross-compiler tool chain with gcc and glibc. But I'm having some problems with the compiler.

When I'm trying to compile a simple file it complains about a missing crti.o and crt1.o.

These files does exist in ${TOOLCHAINPATH}/lib, but I do not know how to instruct the compiler/linker to look their.

So, how can I set the search path for these files?

Thanks in advance